# How to check and use Google Play Service Updated security Provide in react native application to save application from OpenSSL vulnerabilities

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native and app gives an issue in security scan which is related to Update Security Provider.
The application does not use the Google Play Service Updated Security Provider which may leave it vulnerable to future vulnerabilities in OpenSSL Library.
I have found few solution for it on https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider. I have used Patch asynchronously (simply write the given code in my mainActivity) but I don't think its working because issue still persists.

Comment: Is there any solution to it?

Comment: Android Bad Practices: Missing Google Play Services Updated Security Provider
Remediation Effort(Hrs): 0.1  ...please tell me solution of this . still, I did;t get any solution, I have added firebase crashlytics